# ¿Cómo obtener el idcanción que más se repite por cada uno de los idusuarios?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subconsultas, postgresql-13

He intentado obtener la canción que más ha escuchado (la que más se repite en la reproducción) para cada uno de los usuarios. Por ejemplo, si en un conteo de todas las canciones reproducidas por el usuarios `[1]` da que las canciones `[1]` (se reprodujo 10 veces), la canción `[2]`(se reprodujo 5) veces que me devuelva el id de la canción `[1]` ya que esta se reprodujo más cantidad de veces.

Código de ejemplo:

```
SELECT idUsuario, idcanción, count(idcanción)
FROM Reproducciones
GROUP BY idUsuario, idcanción
ORDER BY idusuario
```

Imagen de ilustración:

[image: Imagen de guía]

Como podemos ver en la imagen, el `idusuario` `[1]` ha reproducido varias canciones, pero lo que me interesa es que devuelva el `idcanción` que más reproducciones tuvo con un `(count(idcanción))`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El count te devuelve la cantidad de reproducciones, pero no veo un count en tu query... si ordenas por esa columna, te puede quedar primero ese....

Comment: Me equivoque al no mostrar el SELECT, ya está corregido.

Comment: y si ordenas por count(idcanción)? no termino de entender que buscas...

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener la canción preferida de un usuario en particular o de todos los usuarios a la vez?

Comment: De cada uno de los usuarios, es decir como si fuera la preferida de un usuario en particular, pero por cada uno de los usuarios.

Comment: @jachguate Creo que se refiere a esto: obtener la canción que más se repite o count de cada un usuario, veo que se repite porque varios usuarios han escuchado varias canciones, entonces, al parecer es que debe de mostrar el mayor count de esas canciones y al final solo mostrar el idcanción que más se repite, es posible que hayan varios y no solo 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener la canción preferida de todos los usuarios, puedes valerte de una función de ventana como `rank()` o `row_number()` para *numerar* las filas del agrupamiento de acuerdo a un orden particular y luego quedarte solamente con la primera de cada grupo.

Utilizando cte's para ir paso a paso, partimos de tu consulta de ejemplo:

```
with 
Base as (
SELECT idUsuario, idcanción, count(1) reproducciones
  FROM Reproducciones
GROUP BY idUsuario, idcanción
)
,
Numeracion as (
select   idUsuario
       , idcanción
       , reproducciones
       , row_number() over (partition by idUsuario order by reproducciones desc) NumeroPreferida
  from Base
)
select idUsuario, idCancion, reproducciones
  from Numeracion
 where NumeroPreferida = 1
```

En el segundo paso, voy numerando las canciones de acuerdo a su cantidad de reproducciones en orden descendiente, de manera que la más reproducida tendrá `NumeroPreferida` 1, la siguiente 2, la siguiente 3, y así sucesivamente. La numeración se re-inicia para cada idUsuario (gracias a `partition by`).

Finalmente, hago una consulta sobre esta *tabla* `Numeracion`, quedandome solo con los registros cuyo `NumeroPreferida` sea 1, que es la más escuchada de cada usuario.

Comment: Muchas gracias! es a eso a lo que me refería.

Comment: Es posible llegar al mismo resultado sin CTEs?

Comment: si, usando sentencias del tipo `select x from (select y from (select z from...`. Me parece, sin embargo, que son poco legibles y difíciles de mantener.

Comment: En la solución que diste que función tiene el count(1) reproducciones?

Comment: `count()` cuenta lo que se le pase como parámetro. Ya que cada registro representa una reproducción, le paso un valor constante 1, pues simplemente quiero contar cuantos registros tengo. Finalmente `reproducciones` es el alias que quiero utilizar para esa columna, para poder referenciarla en otras sentencias.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de conseguirlo puede ser usando sub-consulta.

- Primero buscamos los usuarios que han reproducido canciones (`Tabla A`)
- Luego creamos una sub-consulta para obtener la canción favorita de cada uno.

**Ejemplo:**

```
SELECT 
    A.idUsuario,
    (
      SELECT B.idCancion
        FROM Reproducciones AS B
        WHERE B.idUsuario = A.idUsuario
        GROUP BY B.idCancion
        ORDER BY COUNT(B.idCancion) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS idCancionFavorita
FROM Reproducciones AS A
GROUP BY A.idUsuario
ORDER BY A.idUsuario;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u74Dha7z4AutiM8rkHmxLj/0)</kbd>

---

**Comentario:** La sub-consulta se ejecutará tantas veces como usuarios obtengas en la primer consulta, por lo que hacerlo de esta forma puede ser bueno (*pocos usuarios o resultado paginado*) o malo (*muchos usuarios*).