# quiero mostrar el producto y su mejor proveedor con el precio en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

TABLA PRODUCTOS

| prod_id | prod_nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

TABLA PROVEEDORES

| prov_id | prov_nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PEDRO |
| 2 | JUAN |
| 3 | MARIA |

TABLA PRODUCTOSPROVEEDORES

| prodProv_id | prod_id | prov_id | prodProv_precio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 700 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 2000 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 1200 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 2000 |
| 6 | 3 | 3 | 1500 |

RESULT QUERY

| PRODUCTO | PROVEEDOR | PRECIO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | JUAN | 700 |
| B | MARIA | 1200 |
| C | MARIA | 1500 |

### MI CODIGO

`----------micodigo-------------`

```
SELECT  productos.prod_codigo,productos.prod_nombre,proveedores.prov_nit, 
MIN(productosproveedores.prodProv_costo)
FROM productos 
LEFT JOIN productosproveedores on productos.prod_codigo =  productosproveedores.prod_codigo
left JOIN proveedores on proveedores.prov_nit =  productosproveedores.prov_nit
group by productos.prod_codigo,productos.prod_nombre,proveedores.prov_nit
order by productos.prod_codigo;
`
```

1.el problea es que si agrego el nombre del proveedor en el select y lo agrego el el group by me muestra todos los proveedores y sus precios y no tiene en cuenta el menor precio que es el que quiero mostrar.

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo, si lo que pretendes mostrar es, el producto A supongamos que lo venda JUAN, MARIA y PEDRO, de esos 3 quieres mostrar los 3 pero ordenado de menor a mayor precio? o supongamos que JUAN lo da a 300, PEDRO a 400 y MARIA a 500, solo quieres mostrar el de menor en este caso JUAN?  El problema 1 sería JUAN=300, PEDRO=400, MARIA=500..  El problema 2 : JUAN=300

Comment: Prueba con este select                                      
SELECT  productos.prod_codigo,productos.prod_nombre,proveedores.prov_nit, 
        MIN(productosproveedores.prodProv_costo)
 FROM productos 
 LEFT JOIN productosproveedores 
     on productos.prod_codigo = productosproveedores.prod_codigo
 left JOIN proveedores 
     on proveedores.prov_nit =  productosproveedores.prov_nit
 order by productos.prod_nombre;

Comment: Esto puede ayudarte: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/448553/21

Comment: SI, @Omar solo quiero mostrar el de menor precio, es decir mostrar cada producto y el proveedor a menor precio lo ofrece.

Comment: @Omar falta el group by. SELECT productos.prod_codigo,productos.prod_nombre,proveedores.prov_nit, MIN(productosproveedores.prodProv_costo) 
FROM productos 
LEFT JOIN productosproveedores on productos.prod_codigo = productosproveedores.prod_codigo 
left JOIN proveedores on proveedores.prov_nit = productosproveedores.prov_nit 
group by productos.prod_codigo,productos.prod_nombre,proveedores.prov_nit 
order by productos.prod_codigo; --pero mostrara todos los proveedores que es el problema que tengo.

Answer (score 0):

Un opción es utilizando esta query:

Haces un DISTINCT sobre el nombre del producto y ordenas por el precio ascendente (el menor primero).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.prod_nombre)
   p.prod_nombre, pee.prov_nombre, pp.prodProv_precio AS precio
FROM productos p
LEFT JOIN productosproveedores pp on p.prod_id =  pp.prod_id
LEFT JOIN proveedores pee on pee.prov_id =  pp.prov_id
ORDER BY p.prod_nombre, pp.prodProv_precio ASC;
```

Otra opción es utilizando **Window Functions**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   p.prod_nombre,
   first_value(pee.prov_nombre) OVER (PARTITION BY p.prod_id ORDER BY pp.prodProv_precio ASC) AS mejor_proveedor,
   first_value(pp.prodProv_precio) OVER (PARTITION BY p.prod_id ORDER BY pp.prodProv_precio ASC) AS precio
FROM productos p
LEFT JOIN productosproveedores pp on p.prod_id =  pp.prod_id
LEFT JOIN proveedores pee on pee.prov_id =  pp.prov_id
ORDER BY p.prod_nombre;
```

Ambas traen para cada producto el proveedor con el menor precio.

Los nombres que figuran en tus tablas no coinciden con los de tu query.

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono perfectamente.

Comment: De nada @EdwardFaridMayorgaHernandez! Recuerda seleccionar la respuesta que mejor conteste tu pregunta.